# How to check children method has been called in jasmine test cases?

Tags: testcase, jasmine, mock

We use `spyOn(this,"_new")` to track a function call in jasmine. I need to check the children method call in jasmine. My code sample is given below,

Sample code:

```
function perform(option) {
   this.answer=this.perform._sum(option.a+option.b);
   console.log(this.answer);
}
```

My question is how to check the `this.perform.sum(option.a+option.b)` has been called with `spyOn()` in jasmine JavaScript?

I have tried the below way, but it was not worked as much I expected?

```
it("If we pass  arguments to the perform method, ensuring that the sum method has been called or not", function(done) {
    spyOn(this,"perform._sum");

    var option={a:10,b:6};

    this.perform(option);
    expect(this.perform._sum).toHaveBeenCalledWith(option.a,option.b);

    done();
});
```

But above code has not worked. And also, I had posted an issue regarding this [npm-jasmine:Issues](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues). The Question details are given below:

[how to check children method has been  called in jasmine test cases](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/126)

Can anybody tell me, how to check the children method call in jasmine using `spyOn()`?

Comment: Could you post the complete reproducible example? It's difficult to follow the `this` usage - do you have the test in the same file as the code under test?